# Excel VBA Loop Through All Worksheets Except 2 - Paste Array In Separate Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that works in the active sheet, but when I try to add to the code so that it will loop through all worksheets except 2, I get an error and can't figure out how to fix it. The code looks through a timecard with the job# listed on the left and the dates are along the top with reg, OT, & DT column for each date, it then pulls the hours under each date and puts each into a separate row on Sheet3 which is formatted for a .csv upload file. I need the code to run for every sheet except 2, and the number of sheets can change based on the number of timecards needed. I know my working code references the active sheet and the loop doesn't activate each sheet so I've tried adjusting for that. My problem probably lies in the order that I'm tyring to do things. I'm a beginner at VBA, mostly just adjusting others' code to fit my needs. I've tried to find a solution online, but they don't seem to fix my problem. I've been working on this for 2 days, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Working code:

```
Sub CreateCSV()
Dim wsTC As Worksheet, wsCSV As Worksheet
Dim tcAr As Variant, csvAr As Variant
Dim i As Long, k As Long

Set wsTC = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet: Set wsCSV = Sheet3

With wsTC
    '~~> Store the values from the range in an array
    tcAr = .Range("A12:AC25").Value

    '~~> Define your new array
    ReDim csvAr(1 To 29, 1 To 14)

    '~~> Loop through the array and store values in new array
    For i = LBound(tcAr) To UBound(tcAr)

        '~~> Check for Mon Reg
        If tcAr(i, 6) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 6)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mon OT
        If tcAr(i, 7) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 7)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mon DT
        If tcAr(i, 8) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 8)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mileage
        If tcAr(i, 27) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[X8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase            
            csvAr(k, 13) = tcAr(i, 27) * 0.35   'Amount
            csvAr(k, 14) = tcAr(i, 29)   'Memo
        End If

    Next i
End With

    '~~> Output the array
    wsCSV.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(29, 14).Value = csvAr

End Sub
```

Non-working code:

```
Sub TestLoopCreateCSV()
Dim wsTC As Worksheet, wsCSV As Worksheet
Dim tcAr As Variant, csvAr As Variant
Dim i As Long, k As Long

Set wsCSV = Sheet3

For Each wsTC In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

With wsTC

If wsTC.Name <> "Sheet2" And wsTC.Name <> "Sheet3" Then

    '~~> Store the values from the range in an array
    tcAr = .Range("A12:AC25").Value

    '~~> Define your new array
    ReDim csvAr(1 To 29, 1 To 14)

    '~~> Loop through the array and store values in new array
    For i = LBound(tcAr) To UBound(tcAr)

        '~~> Check for Mon Reg
        If tcAr(i, 6) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 6)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mon OT
        If tcAr(i, 7) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 7)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mon DT
        If tcAr(i, 8) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[F8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 12) = tcAr(i, 8)   'Hours
        End If

        '~~> Check for Mileage
        If tcAr(i, 27) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            csvAr(k, 1) = "1"           'Company
            csvAr(k, 2) = wsTC.[R6]     'PR End Date
            csvAr(k, 3) = wsTC.[D6]     'Employee
            csvAr(k, 4) = wsTC.[X8]     'Post Date
            csvAr(k, 5) = tcAr(i, 1)    'Job
            csvAr(k, 6) = tcAr(i, 3)    'Phase
            csvAr(k, 13) = tcAr(i, 27) * 0.35   'Amount
            csvAr(k, 14) = tcAr(i, 29)   'Memo
        End If

    Next i

    '~~> Output the array
    wsCSV.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(29, 14).Value = csvAr

    End If

    End With

Next wsTC

End Sub
```

Comment: you have a `Next i` in there without a loop.

Comment: also your resize is backwards.  `.Resize(Rows,Columns)` so `Resize(14,29)`

Comment: OP - you either have some things misplaced in your code or you took out too much. I'm guessing you opened the `i` loop where you have your comment "rest of code that doesn't change". You should show the complete code so we aren't left guessing

Comment: also you fill `tcar` but try to assign `csvar`  forge the arrays: `wsCSV.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(14,29).Value = .Range("A12:AC25").Value`

Comment: Properly indenting / spacing your code goes a long way in trouble shooting.

Comment: Scott, if I change the order of the resize as you suggested, then my working code doesn't work anymore. My tcAr (time card array) that I'm copying from is 29 columns and my csvAr (.csv array) that I am pasting to is 14 columns.

Comment: Which line errors and what is the error?